# When erasing media in Disk Utility, how can I change the default format?

Tags: macos, disk-utility

Every time I erase my MicroSD card, I need to change the format from `ExFAT` to `MS-DOS (FAT)`. Is there a way to change the default to the latter, or better yet, to default to the current format of the drive I'm erasing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a setting to change, so you might instead script the `diskutil` command to do the erase using AppleScript or another scripting language.

```
diskutil eraseVolume disk12345
```

The `eraseVolume` command just wipes the volume and recreates an empty filesystem to match what was there. You could build a little window to ask for the volume or perhaps even list all the disks and then tell you to insert the drive to be wiped.

You also might use `system_profiler SPCardReaderDataType` or the similar **SPStorageDataType** or **SPUSBDataType** depending on how the cards you wish to erase are connected to the Mac.